# Issue with angularjs date format

Tags: angularjs, date-format

When I tried to view the date in the front end.  I'm getting this:
2015-09-30T16:00:00.000Z``

How can I conver it to 09/30/2015?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [here how to filter dates](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date) with angularjs.

Usage: `{{ date_expression | date : format : timezone}}`